# How to transform text file to schema with biztalk or xslt, or logic apps also?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-2016

I have a text file like this:

```
20201117125512HH  001APPOINTMENT DATA                                    85372
APTHDR0350100000001 1 2CROS04202020-11-25012020-11-25 15:30:00.000000        PIC077120                   128027  2020-11-17 12:50:52.000265 N  N   0000004390000000000186000000                              00000                              PIC077120           023095412
APTDTL035010000000C116780360635000000439PIC077120           023095412
APTHDR0350100000001 1 2CACG05002020-11-25012020-11-25 14:00:00.000000        3501382191/,                183699  2020-11-17 12:51:02.000864 N  Y NS0000013210083300043754000000                              00000                              3501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100203821910000010013501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100202566840000001003501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100203826550000001073501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100203852630000000203501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100203746790000000183501382191/, 1621476023035082
APTDTL035010000000C3100202903510000000753501382191/, 1621476023035082
20201117125512TT  001000000000000000000110000000000
```

i need to transform to schema with some conditions:

- with the first line and last line: just ignore them.
- with the line start with "APTHDR": it's the header data, need to split the data by position
- with the line start with "APTDTL": it is the detail data of the header before it, need to split the data by position.
  i need to transform that file to xml (schema) by biztalk, xslt or logic apps. for now i don't how is that possible to do that?

You guys have any idea or any guys know about that can help me? thanks you guys so much.

Comment: XPath 2 has functions `unparsed-text` to read a text file, `tokenize` to split text (e.g. by line breaks) into a sequence of strings and XSLT 2 has `xsl:analyze-string` to break up strings with regular expressions. Of course even XPath 1 `susbstring` might help if you need to extract parts of a string by position in the string. In XSLT 3 you can even use `unparsed-text-lines` and process that sequence of line strings with grouping e.g. `for-each-group select="unparsed-text-lines('foo.txt') => tail()" group-starting-with=".[starts-with(., 'APTHDR')]"` to create some XML structure.

Comment: Hi Martin, how i can put the file name in unparsed-text-lines like foo.txt

Comment: Both `unparsed-text` and `unparsed-text-lines` expect a URI to the file e.g. a relative one simply as `unparsed-text-lines('foo.txt')` or absolute as `unparsed-text-lines('http://example.com/foo.txt')` or `unparsed-textlines('file:///C:/dir/subdir/foo.txt')`. Inside of XSLT 2 or 3 you would normally have an `<xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string">foo.txt</xsl:param>` and then use `unparsed-text-lines($text-uri)`. How that works exactly in the context of azure logic apps or biztalk I can't tell.

Comment: In BizTalk, create a flat file schema that does also have the first and last line defined, but just don't map them.  For the other lines define them as positional records, with a tag identifier.    Asking for solutions in multiple technologies will probably result in your question being closed

Comment: i already tried to do it, but it isn't work, the result only map for one record

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: See my answer to this question, is is very similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310662/biztalk-debatch-flat-file-with-header-2-repeating-records-and-trailer-with-tag