# Biztalk Debatch flat file with header, 2 repeating records and trailer with tag identifiers

Tags: xsd, schema, biztalk

i have a flat file with header and trailers with Tag Identifiers as APTHDR and APTDTL respectively.

The current file has me miffed however, as it has a repeating record issue.
File Structure:

```
    20data for the summary information 
        
     HE Header of record
        
     DE Detail of record
        
     HE Header of record
        
     DE Detail of record

     DE Detail of record
        
     20 trailler data
```

record 20 = one instance for summary, one instance for trailler
record.

record HE: one HE have multiple DE. one file have multiple HE.

this is the data example:

```
20201117125512HH  001APPOINTMENT DATA                                    85372
 HE0350100000001 1 2CROS04202020-11-25012020-11-25 15:30:00.000000        PIC077120                   128027  2020-11-17 12:50:52.000265 N  N   0000004390000000000186000000                              00000                              PIC077120           023095412
 DE035010000000C116780360635000000439PIC077120           023095412
 HE0350100000001 1 2CACG05002020-11-25012020-11-25 14:00:00.000000        3501382191/,                183699  2020-11-17 12:51:02.000864 N  Y NS0000013210083300043754000000                              00000                              3501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100203821910000010013501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100202566840000001003501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100203826550000001073501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100203852630000000203501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100203746790000000183501382191/, 1621476023035082
 DE035010000000C3100202903510000000753501382191/, 1621476023035082
 20201117125512TT  001000000000000000000110000000000
```

I get the results in the correct placement if I use a single set, but once I try to create a multiple record file it get hosed.
I just have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting them as one XML file, or do you want the sets of HE & DE de-batched into separate messages?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create 3 schemas, a Header, a Body and a Trailer.
Split the file you have into those components so you can test each schema against that part, for the body just have the one HE and multiple DE.

Then you need to create a pipeline with a flat file disassemble component and set all three schema in the properties.

Deploy these, create a receive port and location that uses the pipeline, and have something subscribing to the messages.

Example schemas

Header schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Header" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Header">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="HeaderRecord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="DateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="14" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="64" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Body Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Body" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Body">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="HeaderRecord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name=" HE" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="263" sequence_number="1" pos_offset="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DetailRecord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="2" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name=" DE" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" pos_length="63" pos_offset="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Trailer schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO68310662" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Header" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Header">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="TrailerRecord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="DateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="14" sequence_number="1" pos_offset="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="37" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Output message 1

```
<Body xmlns="http://Scratch.SO68310662">
    <HeaderRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>0350100000001 1 2CACG05002020-11-25012020-11-25 14:00:00.000000        3501382191/,                183699  2020-11-17 12:51:02.000864 N  Y NS0000013210083300043754000000                              00000                              3501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </HeaderRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100203821910000010013501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100202566840000001003501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100203826550000001073501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100203852630000000203501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100203746790000000183501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C3100202903510000000753501382191/, 1621476023035082</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
</Body>
```

Output message 2

```
<Body xmlns="http://Scratch.SO68310662">
    <HeaderRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>0350100000001 1 2CROS04202020-11-25012020-11-25 15:30:00.000000        PIC077120                   128027  2020-11-17 12:50:52.000265 N  N   0000004390000000000186000000                              00000                              PIC077120           023095412</Field1>
    </HeaderRecord>
    <DetailRecord xmlns="">
        <Field1>035010000000C116780360635000000439PIC077120           023095412</Field1>
    </DetailRecord>
</Body>
```